# how to convert subquery SQL to sqlachemy?

Tags: python, sql, group-by, sqlalchemy, subquery

How can I convert the sql to sqlachemy?

My SQL is

```
SELECT ev,
      min(event_time) AS first_event,
      max(event_time) AS last_event,
      min(arrival_time) AS first_arrival,
      max(arrival_time) AS last_arrival,
      count(DISTINCT(device_id)) AS device_id_count,
     (select category_value from A where category = 1 and A.ev = AAA.ev) as category_value
  FROM A as AAA
 where AAA.id <= 2 GROUP BY ev
```

As I know sqlachemy had the `subquery()` function，but I don not understand how to convert `(select category_value from A where category = 1 and A.ev = AAA.ev)` to sqlachemy code

My attempt with SQL alchemy is (formatted for readability)

```
session.query(
    A.env, 
   func.min(A.event_time),
   func.max(A.event_time),
   func.min(A.arrival_time),
   func.max(A.arrival_time),
   func.count(A.device_id.distinct())).filter(A.id >=2 ).group_by(A.env)
```

Comment: Reformatted the SQL + code, rephrased question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert `select category_value from A where category = 1 and A.ev = AAA.ev` into a subquery you should create the query exactly as you normally would and then call its `.label()` method to return a scalar value that can be used in place of a column expression in your main query. The following sqlalchemy code should replicate your original SQL and will echo the generated SQL to the terminal when executed.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, aliased
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_time = Column(String)
    arrival_time = Column(String)
    device_id = Column(String)
    event_time = Column(String)
    ev = Column(String)
    category = Column(Integer)
    category_value = Column(String)

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


AAA = aliased(A, name="AAA")
category_value = session.query(A.category_value).filter(A.category == 1).filter(A.ev == AAA.ev).label("category_value")
query = session.query(
    AAA.ev, 
    func.min(AAA.event_time).label("first_event"),
    func.max(AAA.event_time).label("last_event"),
    func.min(AAA.arrival_time).label("first_arrival"),
    func.max(AAA.arrival_time).label("last_arrival"),
    func.count(AAA.device_id.distinct()).label("device_id_count"),
    category_value,
).filter(AAA.id <= 2).group_by(AAA.ev).all()
```

Comment: thanks EAW, I had try your method, but it shows thad `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "anon_1.category_value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`, it could not work.

Comment: My bad. the `category_value.label("category_value")` was throwing an exception. This was an `AttributeError: 'Alias' object has no attribute 'label'` exception however and not the exception you encountered. I've edited my code and it now works on my system. Let me know if it still fails for you and I'll post a complete working example.

Comment: thanks again, first time，I had fix the error `AttributeError: 'Alias' object has no attribute 'label'`and did it like you do, but then it throw the exception `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "anon_1.category_value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Finally fixed. I'd used `.subquery()` rather than `.label()` to generated the subquery. SQLite didn't object in my testing but Postgres did when you ran it. I've tested the new code with both SQLite and Postgres and it now works.

Comment: thanks, it work now, and I also superised the query time can not be reduced，how can I improve the speed?